# Hyperboloidal compactification of massive scalar wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I have been reading up on hyperboloidal compactifications [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3809). I am thinking about scalar wave equations of the form (context I am working in four dimensional spacetime (three space dimensions, one time), with metric signature -+++, and assuming an asymptotically flat spacetime):

\begin{equation}
\Box\phi - m^2\phi - \lambda \phi^3 = 0,
\end{equation}
where $m^2$ and $\lambda$ are constants. Looking at the techniques in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3809), the author says the it's not yet known if one can hyperboloidally compactify the above wave equation when $m^2\neq0$, while having the equation be regular at future null infinty. Looking at the citations, I haven't found any progress on this.

**My question:**  Is there any work on regular hyperboloidal compactifications (i.e. the equation itself is regular at future null infinity) of the massive scalar wave equation?

More background:

Consider Minkowski space, then the wave equation is
\begin{align}
\left(-\partial_t^2 + \partial_r^2 + \frac{2}{r}\partial_r + \frac{1}{r^2}\Delta_{S^2}\right)\phi
- m^2\phi - \lambda\phi^3=0
.
\end{align}
By rescaling $\phi=r^{-1}\psi$ and multiplying by $r$, we get
\begin{align}
\left(-\partial_t^2 + \partial_r^2 + \frac{1}{r^2}\Delta_{S^2}\right)\psi
- m^2\psi - \frac{1}{r^2}\lambda\psi^3=0
.
\end{align}
Following [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3809), we compactify by setting
\begin{equation}
t = T - f(r), \qquad r = \frac{R}{1-R}
\end{equation}
where $f$ needs to satisfy $\lim_{R\to1} \frac{df}{dr} \sim 1 - (1-R)^2$. It turns out that when we do this the mass term goes as $m^2\psi/(1-R)^2$ in the compactified equations of motion. My hope is that there is a way of hyperboloidally compactifying the equation that avoids this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The singularity of the mass term at null infinity is independent of the foliation. See [Winicour](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.527836) (1988) and [Helfer](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.530038) (1993). One may nevertheless speculate that under certain special scenarios the compactification of the Klein-Gordon equation at null infinity may lead to a regular equation. And this is indeed the case.

Write the wave equation in frequency domain via $\psi = e^{ikt} \Psi$. Ignoring the cubic term
$$ \left(\partial_r^2 + \frac{1}{r^2}\Delta_{S^2} \right) \Psi + (k^2-m^2) \Psi = 0. $$

There is no time in frequency domain, so to transform this equation into hyperboloidal coordinates you simply rescale the unknown $\Psi$ with $e^{-ikf(r)}$ as described [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.2451). The trick in the massive case is to change the rescaling to $e^{-i\sqrt{k^2-m^2} f(r)}$. After compactification, you'll see that the equation is regular at null infinity *for each frequency*.

This is as yet unpublished, but maybe it's worth publishing.